# Hyperledger Fabric "Makefile:107: recipe for target 'license' failed"

Tags: ubuntu, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I try to set up hyperledger fabric in Ubuntu 17 following the guide [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev-setup/build.html). I follow all the steps, the GOPATH is correct and allways has the same error.

```
docker tag hyperledger/fabric-tools hyperledger/fabric-tools:x86_64-1.0.0-alpha3-snapshot-ed020470
LINT: Running code checks..
Checking ./bccsp
Checking ./common
Checking ./core
Checking ./events
Checking ./examples
Checking ./gossip
Checking ./msp
Checking ./orderer
Checking ./peer
Checking ./protos
Checking Go files for license headers ...
The following files are missing license headers:
./orderer/kafka/partitioner.go
./orderer/kafka/partitioner_test.go
./orderer/mocks/util/util.go
./orderer/mocks/util/util_test.go
./test/chaincodes/BadImport/main.go
./protos/common/common_test.go
./protos/common/ledger_test.go
./protos/common/configtx_test.go
./protos/common/configuration_test.go
./protos/common/policies_test.go
./core/comm/connection.go
./core/comm/config_test.go
./core/comm/server.go
./core/comm/creds_test.go
./core/comm/creds.go
./core/comm/config.go
./core/config/config_test.go
./core/deliverservice/deliveryclient.go
./peer/node/start.go
./peer/common/common_test.go
**Makefile:107: recipe for target 'license' failed make: *** [license] Error 1**
```

These are the original and they don't have any modification... Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stuck on a similar issue. The make error I was getting also mentioned several *.go files.

```
The following files are missing SPDX-License-Identifier headers:
core/deliverservice/client.go
core/deliverservice/client_test.go 
core/deliverservice/deliveryclient_test.go
Please replace the Apache license header comment text with:
SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
Makefile:111: recipe for target 'license' failed
make: *** [license] Error 1`
```

What solved my issue as mentioned [here](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5282) was adding the following at the top of mentioned files.

`/*
 Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved. 
 SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
*/`

Just for reference, the faulting files in my case were `client.go`, `client_test.go` and `deliveryclient_test.go` under the directory `src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/deliverservice/`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error with a different project and figured out that the docker-compose had the old version.
So I ran
`pip install docker-compose` to update the docker-compose and then it worked